# React component not re-rendering after props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to filter a set of objects in the state whenever the user clicks on a button on my component. The logic of the filtering works fine, but when it gets back to the component, the filtered objects are missing and instead the property is undefined. Am I missing a lifecycle method?

The click event:

```
<div onClick={this.filterMyPosts}>My Posts</div>
...
<div>
    {this.renderPosts()}
</div>
```

filterMyPosts

```
filterMyPosts() {
   this.props.updateFilter("myPosts");
   // filtering function uses switch statement based on strings to filter posts
}
```

The component container:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {currentUser: state.session.currentUser,
    posts: allPostsByFilter(state.posts, state.filter, state.session.currentUser.id, state.bookmarks)}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateFilter: (filter) => dispatch(updateFilter(filter))
})
```

The filtering takes place in a different file, which returns the filtered events in an object. That logic has no errors.

***The problem***: By the time it gets to the following function, "posts" is undefined. So somewhere along the way, the filtered posts are not making it back to the component.

```
renderPosts() {
    return (
    <div className ="user-profile-posts">
      <ul>
       {Object.keys(this.props.posts).map(id => <PostIndexItem 
        key={`posts-index-item${id}`} 
        post={this.props.posts[id]}
        user={true}
        />)}
      </ul>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

**EDIT - filter function**

```
export const allPostsByFilter = (filter, currentUserId, posts) => {
  switch (filter) {
case "myPosts":

  let postKeys = Object.keys(posts).filter( (id) => {
    return(posts[id].user_id === currentUserId)
  });
  let userPosts = {}
  postKeys.forEach( (key) => userPosts[key] = posts[key])
  let newPosts = {}

  let postKeys = Object.keys(posts).filter( (id) => {
    return (Object.keys(userPosts).includes(id))
  });
  eventKeys.forEach( (key) => newPosts[key] = posts[key])

  return newPosts

default: 
      return posts
```

Answer (score 1):

You lose `this` context when binding your action.

```
<div onClick={this.filterMyPosts}>My Posts</div>
```

Change the invocation to

```
<div onClick={() => this.filterMyPosts()}>My Posts</div>
```

This assures `this` in your `filterMyPosts` method. Without it, props is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

State is missing posts as one of the property / reducer. events should be replaced by posts.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {currentUser: state.session.currentUser,
    events: allPostsByFilter(state.posts, state.filter, state.session.currentUser.id, state.bookmarks)}
};
```

There is a mismatch in parameters between the allPostsByFilter call and the function definition.

The first parameter should be the filter. Instead posts is being passed as the first parameter.

The dispatch method - updateFilter should change the state of the filter for allPostByFilter to be triggered.

Comment: Sorry that is a typo from earlier, I have changed it above.

Comment: Can you share allPostsByFilter function? Maybe, there is a condition where you are not returning.

Comment: I added the code above. Though I do not think it is the issue. The issue is the updateFilter dispatch is updating the filter on the state, but that is not causing 'mapStateToProps' to execute again, meaning the filtered events never really make it to the user. I think there must be some lifecycle method I could use.